# Conversion from VB6 to C# string manipulation

Tags: c#, .net, vb6

VB6 code is as follows:

```
record = Collection & Right(TableName, Len(TableName) - (InStr(1, TableName, "_<idNo>_") + 7))
```

I've tried keeping the logic when changing it to c# but doesnt seem to work.

```
collection = 111111   
Record = collection + tablename.Substring(tablename.Length -  tablename.Length - tablename.IndexOf("_<idNo>_", 1) + 7);
```

(VB6)InStr is (C#)indexOf
See: http://bytes.com/topic/net/answers/108174-c-equilivant-instr

(VB6)`Right` is (C#)`Substring` and I'm following the template of how they change one to another.
See: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/9598905f-912f-4ea7-b954-eb2f48328ce5/c-equivalent-for-right-of-vb

Expecting: 111111fiddlein

Getting: 111111o>_fiddlein

Also, when editing the `+ 7` at the end it doesn't seem to eliminate the underscore between the concatenation.
But instead I get: 111111o>_fiddlein

Comment: `tablename.Length-tablename.Length`?

Comment: yeah, i understand that's not needed, im just following how it's been suggested using what is considered to be equivalents.

Comment: What does `tablename` contain for example?

Comment: it would be easier to help if we could see an example of what was being parsed

Comment: tablename = t_<idNo>_fiddlein

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume the following:

```
string collection = "111111";
string tablename = "t_<idNo>_fiddlein"; // anything before '<idNo>_' will not be observed
```

Then this should do it:

```
string result = collection + tablename.Substring(tablename.IndexOf("_<idNo>_") + 8);
```

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is VB6 InStr function is 1 based, and C# IndexOf function is 0 based.